# How to limit a dot string to only one character even when holding down a non-number key

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm creating a input validation to allow only a numeric and dot input.

It does limit the dot character to one onkeypress but when holding down a non-number key it's not.

```
 <input class="form-control" type="text" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9.{1}$]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');" />
```

How can i limit the dot string to one even when holding down a non-number key?

Comment: What if the user copy/paste in the input box with the mouse?

Comment: Why is it downvoted?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need javascript here: use `input` with type `number` (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number)). If the typed user input is invalid (it *may* contain more dots), the input has no value (check it with the button of the snippet). For example:

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener(
  "click", 
  () => {
      const val = document.querySelector("input").value;
      console.log( val || "Invalid");
    }
);
```

```html
<input type="number" step="0.1" min="1" max="20" value="1.0">
<button>show value</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
^(?=^[^.]*\.?[^.]*$).+$
```

[image]

```html
<form>
  <input type='text' pattern='^(?=^[^.]*\.?[^.]*$).+$'/>
  <button typ='submit'>submit</button>
</form>
```

***Note:-*** If you need one `.` to be must you can change above regex to

```
^(?=^[^.]*\.[^.]*$).+$
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `<input type="number" />` or `<input pattern="[0-9]*\.?[0-9] />` as the others have suggested.

However,

## If you want to do it "manually"

You could use the `onkeypress` attribute. This is the event which fires for every repetition of a character. After firing this event, the browser updates the input value.

**Canceling the event**

If we return a `false` like such: `onkeypress="return false"`, you will notice that the input value won't update anymore, no matter what key you press. We can even add a condition: `onkeypress="if(event.key != '0') return false;"`. In this case, you will only be able to write 0s in the input.

So, this is the event during which we will have to check, and make up our mind if we are going to allow the newly pressed key to have an effect. We will return `true` or `false` accordingly. However, there is only one little problem.

**Composing the new value**

Before we are going to decide if we allow the newly pressed key to have an effect, we need to see what effect it would have. We need to see how the input value will look like after this event. So we are going to compute it. Right now, the input still contains the current (without the new character) value.

### Implementation

The JavaScript function:

```
function checkNumber(input, event){

    //- We have the old value in input, and the currently pressed key in event.key
    //- So we have the compute the new to be value of the input, to check if it's correct
    //- To do this, we break the text into an array of characters, and insert the key
    //- at the cursor's position - Check on MDN what Array.prototype.splice() does
    var newValue = input.value.split('');
    newValue.splice(this.selectionStart, this.selectionEnd-this.selectionStart, event.key);
    newValue = newValue.join(''); //- Put it back into string form

    return /^[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*$/.test(newValue);

}
```

And to use it:

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" onkeypress="return checkNumber(this, event);" />
```